# Entity Framework5 is not returning the proper data,it is repeating data from a single record

Tags: entity-framework

Entity Framework 5 is not returning the proper data. It is repeating data from a single record

[image]

```
 var bankDepositDateQuery = db.bank_deposit.Where(e=>e.AgentID ==item.AgentID).ToList();
```

It's repeating the data with single Record [image]

How to solve this?

Comment: according to the query, the result seems correct: every row as the same AgentID, that is 1 in this case. What do you expect the result to be (more precisely)?

Comment: if you see MySQL record result SELECT * FROM ntc_sales.bank_deposit  where agentid=1 first four record are same thats' right but last 2 records are also showing same records it should show the deposit amount 500 here I am getting 1000 but count is right count=6

Comment: here  am getting all th e 6 reocrds same records I don't have primary key for my table so I added the [key] for agentid still not working properly

Comment: datetime seems different to me, but if the query in MySql returns 6 records, you can't expect a different behavior from EF

Comment: soryy u didn't understood my problem I want MySQL result same as EF result but here in EF getting same record multiple time  the result is different from mysql

Comment: my problem as like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15815533/entity-framework-is-not-returning-the-proper-data-it-is-repeating-data-from-a-s